# Unable to set Constraints to MediaRecorder in JavaScript for Mozilla Firefox OS (KaiOS)

Tags: javascript, firefox-os, web-mediarecorder, kaios

I am creating a MediaRecorder app for KaiOS. I wanted to disable noiseSuppression and set several other constraints as specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getSupportedConstraints).

I observed that these constraints are not being respected while I set them in my code. I still get noise Suppressed audio. 
Needed some help on this front. Setting constraints is very straight forward and I am sure I am doing it right. It's just not getting respected on KaiOS devices. Could really use some help here.

Comment: These constraints should be set on the MediaStream request, not on the MediaRecorder.

Comment: @Kaiido
Can you show me a very basic syntax for the same in my relevance? That is when i use the MediaRecorder.

Comment: `const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices({video: true, audio: true,  noiseSuppression: true}); const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);` But honestly, that would be easier if you do provide what you have.